# Query parameter string in cakePHP 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4, cakephp-3.3

I'm getting null query parameter string even though passing query parameter string like this `login?redirect=%2Farticles%2Fadd`. 
I have tried with `$this->request->getQuery('redirect');` and `$this->request->query('redirect');` but no luck.
Does anyone have any idea that where it would be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not setup your URL Route properly in your `config/routes.php` file. When you are interested to pass any route parameter to your controller action you should configure your route proper way. Although your question is not written detailedly.

I hope you will get much more information from this articles.

[Passing Parameters to Action](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)